# TPUEstimator error -- AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.ops.tpu_ops' has no attribute 'cross_replica_sum'

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I have written a tensorflow code using the TPUEstimator, but I am having problems running it in use_tpu=False mode. I would like to run it on my local computer to make sure that all the operations are TPU-compatible. The code works fine with the normal Estimator. Here is my master code:

```
import logging
from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu_config, tpu_estimator, tpu_optimizer
from tensorflow.contrib.cluster_resolver import TPUClusterResolver
from capser_7_model_fn import *
from capser_7_input_fn import *
import subprocess
from absl import flags

flags.DEFINE_bool(
    'use_tpu', False,
    'Use TPUs rather than plain CPUs')

tf.flags.DEFINE_string(
    "tpu", default='$TPU_NAME',
    help="The Cloud TPU to use for training. This should be either the name "
    "used when creating the Cloud TPU, or a grpc://ip.address.of.tpu:8470 "
    "url.")

tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", LOGDIR, "Estimator model_dir")

flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'save_checkpoints_secs', 1000,
    'Interval (in seconds) at which the model data '
'should be checkpointed. Set to 0 to disable.')

flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'save_summary_steps', 100,
'Number of steps which must have run before showing summaries.')

tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("iterations", 1000,
"Number of iterations per TPU training loop.")

tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("num_shards", 8, "Number of shards (TPU chips).")

tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 1024,
                                "Mini-batch size for the training. Note that this "
                                "is the global batch size and not the per-shard batch.")

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS

if FLAGS.use_tpu:
    my_project_name = subprocess.check_output(['gcloud', 'config', 'get-value', 'project'])
    my_zone = subprocess.check_output(['gcloud', 'config', 'get-value', 'compute/zone'])
    cluster_resolver = TPUClusterResolver(
        tpu=[FLAGS.tpu],
        zone=my_zone,
        project=my_project_name)
    master = TPUClusterResolver(tpu=[os.environ['TPU_NAME']]).get_master()
else:
    master = ''

my_tpu_run_config = tpu_config.RunConfig(
    master=master,
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    save_checkpoints_secs=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_secs,
    save_summary_steps=FLAGS.save_summary_steps,
    session_config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True),
    tpu_config=tpu_config.TPUConfig(iterations_per_loop=FLAGS.iterations, num_shards=FLAGS.num_shards),
)


# create estimator for model (the model is described in capser_7_model_fn)
capser = tpu_estimator.TPUEstimator(model_fn=model_fn_tpu,
                                    config=my_tpu_run_config,
                                    use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
                                    train_batch_size=batch_size,
                                    params={'model_batch_size': batch_size_per_shard})

# train model
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)  # to show info about training progress
capser.train(input_fn=train_input_fn_tpu, steps=n_steps)
```

I have a capsule network defined in model_fn_tpu, which returns the TPUEstimator spec. The optimizer is a standard AdamOptimizer. I have made all the changes explained here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_tpu#optimizer to make my code compatible with TPUEstimator. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/doerig/PycharmProjects/capser/TPU_playground.py", line 85, in <module>
    capser.train(input_fn=train_input_fn_tpu, steps=n_steps)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 363, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 843, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 856, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 831, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_estimator.py", line 2016, in _model_fn
    features, labels, is_export_mode=is_export_mode)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_estimator.py", line 1121, in call_without_tpu
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, is_export_mode=is_export_mode)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_estimator.py", line 1317, in _call_model_fn
    estimator_spec = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\PycharmProjects\capser\capser_7_model_fn.py", line 101, in model_fn_tpu
    **output_decoder_deconv_params)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\PycharmProjects\capser\capser_model.py", line 341, in capser_model
    loss_training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), name="training_op")
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 424, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\doerig\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_optimizer.py", line 113, in apply_gradients
    summed_grads_and_vars.append((tpu_ops.cross_replica_sum(grad), var))
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.ops.tpu_ops' has no attribute 'cross_replica_sum'
```

Any ideas to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: We're interested in reproducing your error but are having difficulties. In particular, while your master code is a complete module, it imports some modules that we do not have access to (and feature in your stacktrace), those being `capser_7_input_fn` and `capser_7_model_fn`. Is there some way that we can stub these out to meaningfully attempt to reproduce your error message?

Comment: note on above comment, liamdalton is part of Google's Cloud TPU team.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is either a bug in the version of TensorFlow you are using + Windows, or else an issue with your build of TensorFlow.

For example, when I chase down the file `tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_optimizer.py` [in the TF 1.4 branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py), I see that tpu_ops is imported as:

`from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.ops import tpu_ops`

and if you chase that to [the relevant file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/ops/tpu_ops.py), you see:

```
if platform.system() != "Windows":
  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,unused-import,g-import-not-at-top
  from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.ops.gen_tpu_ops import *

  from tensorflow.contrib.util import loader
  from tensorflow.python.platform import resource_loader
  # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,unused-import,g-import-not-at-top

  _tpu_ops = loader.load_op_library(
      resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("_tpu_ops.so"))
else:
  # We have already built the appropriate libraries into the binary via CMake
  # if we have built contrib, so we don't need this
  pass
```

Following up with the other TF branches that existed at the time of this posting, we see similar comments [in](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py#L22) [1.5](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/ops/tpu_ops.py#L26-L46), [in](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py#L22) [1.6](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/ops/tpu_ops.py#L26-L104), [in](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py#L22) [1.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/ops/tpu_ops.py#L27-L105), [in](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py#L22) [1.8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/ops/tpu_ops.py#L27-L105), and [in](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_optimizer.py#L22) [1.9](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/ops/tpu_ops.py#L27-L105).

I strongly suspect this would not occur under Linux, but I might test this later and edit this answer.

Comment: This also happens in Linux.